# Database Schema for Appointment Scheduling with Time Slots

Tags: sql, database, calendar, schema, scheduling

I am looking to create an appointment booking/scheduling system for Beauty Professionals and Salons.

On one end we have a client looking to book an appointment for a service and on the other we have many providers that have set their schedules AND offer that certain service.

A provider, upon signing up is allowed to pick their days of work and hours. This is planned to be done through web or mobile app, they select a day from the Current Month and then they select hours from 6AM to 9PM.

I have two almost identical tables that distinguish Freelancers ( Individual Beauty Professionals) and Salons respectively where each row in the tables has information on their profiles and a list of id's about the Services that they offer.

Freelancers - Salons
|Id|Email|FirstName|LastName|Services|ServiceAreas|Country|State|City|Zip|Street|

Additionally I have a table called Services that stores:

|Id|Name|Price|Time|Category| - The time column suggest how long does the service last.

|01|Waxing|50.00|30|HAIR REMOVAL|

Question is what is a good schema for storing the Beauty Professionals daily available slots, the Services, such that upon Client search I can give them a list of all available professionals who's schedules are fit for the time of that service.

Answer (score -3):

Relational Schema will be very good for this system.